Почему анимации перехода в приложении заменяются анимацией исчезновения, если в стилях добавить <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
У меня есть приложение с анимациями при переходе между экранами. Если в основной стиль этого приложения добавить <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>, то все эти анимации станут анимацией исчезновения или появления. С чем это может быть связано и как это можно исправить?
